# Collapsing entries with duplicate index values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
bids = [100, 101, 101, 102]
offers = [101, 102, 102.25, 103]
data = {'bids': bids, 'offers': offers}
index = [0, 1, 1, 2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index)
print df

   bids  offers
0   100  101.00
1   101  102.00
1   101  102.25
2   102  103.00
```

How can I reindex df so that the latest value for a given index in each column is used? In this example, I'd want index 1 to have [101, 102.25]

Comment: how do you mean latest? the sequence on how you add the row? or you have a datetime reference? You need to be clear on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) and then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) and pass param `take_last=True` and then set the index back

```
In [181]:
df.reset_index().drop_duplicates('index',take_last=True).set_index('index')

Out[181]:
       bids  offers
index              
0       100  101.00
1       101  102.25
2       102  103.00
```

A more elegant way is to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on the index and call [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last):

```
In [183]:    
df.groupby(df.index).last()

Out[183]:
   bids  offers
0   100  101.00
1   101  102.25
2   102  103.00
```

Comment: "take_last" = nice one

Answer (score 1):

From what you have described, I take a wild guess you want the "last" row in the result. In this case you can simply use `.tail`:

```
In [1]: %paste
import pandas as pd
bids = [100, 101, 101, 102]
offers = [101, 102, 102.25, 103]
data = {'bids': bids, 'offers': offers}
index = [0, 1, 1, 2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index)

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   bids  offers
0   100  101.00
1   101  102.00
1   101  102.25
2   102  103.00

In [3]: df.ix[1]
Out[3]:
   bids  offers
1   101  102.00
1   101  102.25

In [4]: df.ix[1].tail(1)
Out[4]:
   bids  offers
1   101  102.25
```

from the docs:

> DataFrame.tail(n=5)¶
>
> Returns last n rows

Comment: While not what I was looking for, this is also nice to know. I was not aware tail worked in this way. Thanks